# Documentation conventions for Swift enums

Tags: swift

On the [Apple API docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckreferenceaction/1515196-deleteself) the enumeration is listed as `deleteSelf` yet in my Xcode the actual enumeration seems to be `DeleteSelf` - note the capitalisation difference at the start. Not a big deal but wasted some time trying to figure out why it would not recognise that enumeration.

Is there some documentation convention or is that a mistake on the Apple site?

Comment: Objective-C enums were imported as Swift enums with a uppercase first letter in Swift 2, and are imported as Swift enums with a lowercase first letter in Swift 3. It *should* be described somewhere in the Xcode 8 release notes.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see someone has just added an answer to that effect as well.

Comment: Someone? – Three up to now :)

Comment: So fast! Also feel free to add your own answer if you like - detailing the origin of the changes i.e. Swift native versus not depending on version and I'll accept that since technically you were first (via comment).

Comment: I think the existing answers contain enough information, there is no need to add another one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the updated API Guidelines in Swift 3. Before Swift 3 enumeration cases were supposed to be written in UpperCamelCase, whereas now the standard has changed to lowerCamelCase.
The inconsistencies that you've experienced might be due to the fact that you are not using Swift 3.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using Xcode 7.x, right ?
On Xcode 8, every enum cases has followed `camelCase` rules.

More details here:
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of swift, swift 3, the naming convention of enums has changed.

The name displayed on the Apple site is the newest version, so the enums are all in camelCase. On the other hand, you haven't updated Xcode yet, so you will only see the enum values in PascalCase, which is the old naming convention for it.

You don't need to worry about this *at all*. When you decides to update to Swift 3, Xcode can migrate all these things for you!